# SQL Procedure not working according to sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I wanted to write stored procedure for login table.

This procedure involves, checking if LogInID already exists, and if it exists then dont allow to insert record with same LogInID.

I procedure is as follows:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE logTRAN
@id   varchar(25),
@pass varchar(25)
AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION

insert into login values(@id,@pass)

IF EXISTS (select count(*) from login where LogInID=@id)
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'USER ALREADY EXISTS'
        ROLLBACK
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END
```

I execute it as follows:

`exec logTRAN '0L036','aaa'` //this is repeated record with LogInID '0L036'

But Record gets inserted with following result:

```
(1 row(s) affected)
USER ALREADY EXISTS
Msg 266, Level 16, State 2, Procedure logTRAN, Line 0
Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates that a COMMIT or ROLLBACK TRANSACTION statement is missing. Previous count = 2, current count = 0.
```

What can be the mistake in my stored procedure?

Please guid me.

Comment: You should name your columns in the insert statement.  The user will always exist after you do the insert so that will always fail.  You should not have a `COUNT` inside an `EXISTS`.  Either return the count and check against that, or use `*` as your column list.

Comment: I could be mistaken, but you should have a `BEGIN` after the `AS`, and end your proc with `END`

Comment: @RobertMcKee nope, not necessarily. But first comment worked out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your SP to

```
CREATE PROCEDURE logTRAN
   @id   varchar(25),
   @pass varchar(25)
AS
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM login WHERE LogInID = @id)
    PRINT 'USER ALREADY EXISTS'
ELSE
    INSERT INTO login VALUES(@id, @pass)
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9314d/3)** demo

On a side note: IMHO you don't need an SP for this at all. That what a `UNIQUE` constraint is for.

Answer (score 1):

Change your query like below:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE logTRAN
(
   @id   varchar(25),
   @pass varchar(25)
)
AS
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS (SELECT LogInID from login where LogInID=@id)
  BEGIN
     PRINT 'User Already Exists'
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
     INSERT INTO login Values(@id,@pass)
  END
END
RETURN
```

Or if you don't want to print just use:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE logTRAN
(
   @id   varchar(25),
   @pass varchar(25)
)
AS
BEGIN
  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT LogInID from login where LogInID=@id)
  BEGIN
     INSERT INTO login Values(@id,@pass)
  END
END
RETURN
```

**I would recommend to use peterm's Answer. You should use SELECT 1 inplace of SELECT LogInID.**

Comment: You should use peterm's approach of SELECT 1. It is better than mine.

Comment: In theory the database doesn't even have to retrieve LogInID from the table, in reality, because it is in an exists statement it should get optimized away anyhow.

Comment: @Freelancer, Actually,you don't need any column in select coz you just needed to check if Id exists. I took Id in select but it is of no use. I am also new learner so today I learn new things from your question by peterm's answer. Thanks to him and u also.

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter what you'll use because `EXISTS` ignores that part altogether. `1` is just shorter and IMHO cleaner but that's just personal preference.